# lasagne.layers.DenseLayer: "__init__() takes at least 3 arguments"

Tags: python, deep-learning, theano, lasagne

I'm using Lasagne+Theano to create a ResNet and am struggling with the use of DenseLayer. If i use the example on http://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/layers/dense.html it works.

```
l_in = InputLayer((100, 20))
l1 = DenseLayer(l_in, num_units=50)
```

But if I want to use it in my project:

```
#other layers

resnet['res5c_branch2c'] = ConvLayer(resnet['res5c_branch2b'], num_filters=2048, filter_size=1, pad=0, flip_filters=False)
resnet['pool5'] = PoolLayer(resnet['res5c'], pool_size=7, stride=1, mode='average_exc_pad', ignore_border=False)
resnet['fc1000'] = DenseLayer(resnet['pool5'], num_filter=1000)

Traceback (most recent call last):File "convert_resnet_101_caffe.py", line 167, in <module>
resnet['fc1000'] = DenseLayer(resnet['pool5'], num_filter=1000)TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DenseLayer` takes two positional arguments: `incoming, num_units`. You are instantiating it like this:

```
DenseLayer(resnet['pool5'], num_filter=1000)
```

Note that this is different than the example code:

```
DenseLayer(l_in, num_units=50)
```

Since you are passing a keyword argument that is *not* `num_units` as the second argument, I think `num_filter` is being interpreted as one of the `**kwargs`, and `DenseLayer is still wanting that`num_units` argument, and raising an error since you don't provide it.

You can either provide a `num_units` argument before `num_filter`, or if that was just a typo, change `num_filter` to `num_units`. (The second option seems more likely to me since, although I am not familiar with the library that you are using, I do not see any reference to `num_filter` in the documentation you linked, although some classes seem to take a `num_filters` - note the trailing `s` - argument.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that :) it was a typo